# Bitbucket tries to merge Master into Develop when I make pull request from feature branch into Master

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, branch

I wanted a quick fix in Master branch and I made feature branch about it. I made pull request from the feature branch to Master and when I tried to merge it Bitbucket automatically wants to merge Master branch into Develop showing me this image:

[image: this image]

And when I click merge it really tries to merge them (it cannot because of conflicts).

Any ideas - is it a configuration or something?

EDIT: It turned out it is a configuration in BitBucket to which I didn't have access. It was configured to always merge in dev branch by mistake.